# Generating a list of file names from the current project from a silverlight application?

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, directory, filepath

I'm having some trouble trying to get a list of files stored within a folder that's stored within my Silverlight application client project. I'm trying to collect a list of file names of images to dynamically create URIs based on the files within that folder. All I need is a list of the file names.

I've tried:

```
App.GetResourceStream(new Uri(PathName));
```

and this works fine for getting files I know the name of. But I haven't found a way of returning a list of files yet.

My project is called TestWebsite
The the files would be stored within "TestWebsite\Images\ConceptArt\"
and all the files will be of the same image format e.i. '.jpg'

I have also tried this:

```
var result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\UserName\Pictures\ConceptArt\", "*.JPG");
```

but this needs access which seems more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is SL which is Browser based, so if you try to do things outside the SL sandbox, you are going to have to deal with Security.  That is the nature of SL.  If you could use local storage, then you wouldn't have the same issue.  Or if your app is putting the files there, keep a list in local storage.

Greg

Comment: Looks like I'll need to build a list in a text file then, well thanks anyway should be easy enough to update :D